# JavaScript hide/show is not working with onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to hide some content when a value is selected in a dropdown box.

```js
function order()
{
  var x = $("#ddlViewBy").val();
  if(x=="high")
  {
    $("#man_cont").hide();
    $("#man_cont1").show();
  }
  else if(x=="low")
  {
    $("#man_cont").show();
    $("#man_cont1").hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#man_cont").hide();
    $("#man_cont1").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="arnge" class="selectmenu" id="ddlViewBy" onchange="order()">
  <option value="man_cont"></option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
</select>

<div id="man_cont" class="foo man_cont">
  //some contents
</div>
<div id="man_cont1" class="foo man_cont1" style="display:none;">
  //some contentss
</div>
```

can you Please help me out to complete this.

Comment: You are mixing with jquery and javascript. Make sure you have loaded jquery if you using `$`

Comment: yes I have added jquery library.

Comment: @fortune: why you recommended such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @panther i deleted my comment. OP commented that he already added jquery library. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Your code [appears to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/hcqyxdz9/). Please include the errors that you have

Comment: why did you changed and accept syed answer?As I know you accepted panther answer before.even he just copy @panthers answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works me well.

```
<select name="arnge" class="selectmenu" id="ddlViewBy" onchange="order(this)">
  <option value="man_cont"></option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
</select>

<div id="man_cont" class="foo man_cont">
 //some content
    low
</div>
<div id="man_cont1" class="foo man_cont1" style="display:none;">
 //some content
    high
</div>

<script>
function order(el) {
  var x = el.value;

  if (x == "high") {
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (x == 'low') {
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'none';  
  }
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oejdz7fk/1/

I made only three changes:
1. add param to `order` function and avoid specifying element ID in the first `order` function line (just makes code better and you can change to elem ID without lose the functionality)
2. switched jQuery selectors for pure JS in `if-else` part. I expect you forgot to link jQuery regarding the `x` definition.
3. hide both divs when non-option is selected from dropdown (`<option value="man_cont">`)

Comment: Sidenote: This works, however and just to let you know that, whenever the option that shows nothing in the dropdown is selected after chosen either option after, will show up as "//some content low", whether that is what the OP wants or not. Will let the OP decide ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I've updated my answer, added there `else` which hides both divs.

Comment: Ah nice. It's always good to have some form of default value ;-) good show

Comment: If OP included JQuery why he need to change his code to basic javascript style?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: because he added this information 10 minuges after my answer :-) What's more, he set `var x` using pureJS and this isn't task for jQuery, so I only continue with the pureJS solution. Nothing bad. I wrote that in point `2` under my code that he probably forgot to link jQuery. In this piece of code jQuery is not required and pure solution is the fastest (who knows, maybe OP unlink jQuery when he knows he doesn't need that for this task :-) ).

Comment: Your solution is ok.But there is a little difference between `$("#man_cont").show();` and `document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'block';`.It will work because div element normally `blcok` element.But will not work if he set different display style for div element.But Jquery automatically detects it.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: I know that. The code above is for the situation in the question, with no additional styles divs are block. If you know that element is block or inline, you are able to make the code faster, without detect known facts.

Answer (score 2):

Well I just making this answer simple.
As Op says he included jQuery he can little modify his code like this way

```
        function order()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
            //var x = $("#ddlViewBy").val();//You can replace previous line with this as you included jQuyer
            if(x=="high")
            {
                $("#man_cont").hide();
                $("#man_cont1").show();
            }
            else if(x=="low")//You just missed this Option that's why it was not working as you want
            {
                $("#man_cont").show();
                $("#man_cont1").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#man_cont").hide();
                $("#man_cont1").hide();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> [CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/1Lyhbcvu/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
order = function
{
var x = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
if(x=="high")
{
$("#man_cont").hide();
$("#man_cont1").show();
}
else
{
$("#man_cont").show();
$("#man_cont1").hide();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="arnge" class="selectmenu" id="ddlViewBy" onchange="order()">
<option value="man_cont"></option>
<option value="high">high</option>
<option value="low">low</option>
 </select>
 <div id="man_cont" class="foo man_cont">
 // some content
 </div>
 <div id="man_cont1" class="foo man_cont1" style="display:none;">
 // some content1
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this answer will get down-vote.I am sure OP missed including jQuery and he includes it.

Answer (score 1):

code is working fine.but if you want to hide both div when nothing selected in dropdown then you have to give display:none css to both div default.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'block';
```

**instead of :**

```
$("#man_cont").hide();
$("#man_cont1").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you.

```
<select name="arnge" class="selectmenu" id="ddlViewBy" onchange="order(this)">
  <option value="man_cont"></option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
</select>

<div id="man_cont" class="foo man_cont">
 //some content
    low
</div>
<div id="man_cont1" class="foo man_cont1" style="display:none;">
 //some content
    high
</div>

<script>
function order(data) {
  var d = data.value;

  if (d == "high") {
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (d == 'low') {
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('man_cont1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('man_cont').style.display = 'none';  
  }
}
</script>
```